# How do I reinstall Facebook?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, facebook

I deleted Facebook app by accident and now I cannot reinstall. It's not in the store so I'm at a loss. I know there's a way of restoring old apps but I can't find it. Now have very limited access to Facebook and cannot get notifications or messages.

Comment: It shows in the store for me - what device are you using, and which country are you in (according to your Microsoft account)?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I got this link from the Store, does it work for you: 
https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9WZDNCRFJ2WL